# Is it possible for K Mean cluster has no member?

Tags: k-means, centroid

I'm currently using K Mean for clustering files. Some question occur to me, is it possible that the cluster has no member at all? If so, what is happen to the centroid of the cluster? Is it equal as the value before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can happen.

It depends on your implementation what is then happening. Some leave the cluster center as is, some reduce k, some choose a new cluster center, some crash badly.